# Multiple rails application inside a single ubuntu server- digital ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean

I have successfully deployed two rails application inside a single digital ocean server,Enabled the sites inside `nginx` as well.

nginx.conf

```
upstream puma_app {
 server unix:///home/rails/firstapp/shared/tmp/sockets/firstapp- 
 puma.sock;
}

upstream puma_sapp {
 server unix:///home/rails/second/shared/tmp/sockets/secondapp- 
 puma.sock;
}

server {
 listen 80 default_server;
 # server_name example.com;

 root /home/rails/firstapp/current/public;
 access_log /home/rails/firstapp/current/log/nginx.access.log;
 error_log /home/rails/firstapp/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

 location ^~ /assets/ {
  gzip_static on;
  expires max;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
 }

try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
location @puma {
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_redirect off;

proxy_pass http://puma_app;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
client_max_body_size 10M;
keepalive_timeout 10;
}

server {
 listen [::]:8080 ipv6only=on default_server;

 root /home/rails/secondapp/current/public;
 access_log /home/rails/secondapp/current/log/nginx.access.log;
 error_log /home/rails/secondapp/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

 location ^~ /assets/ {
  gzip_static on;
  expires max;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
 }

try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
location @puma {
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_redirect off;

proxy_pass http://puma_app;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
client_max_body_size 10M;
keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

i added the site-enabled as well

when i run, `grep -R "root" /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

i got

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/firstapp:  root /home/rails/firstapp 
/current/public;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/secondapp:  root /home/rails/secondapp 
 /current/public;
```

I can access the first application using the ip of the droplet provided by the digital ocean server.How can i access the second application ?